# conclude that $x^{|G|} = 1_G$ by taking $H = \langle x\rangle \subset G$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Conclude from Lagrange's theorem that $x^{|G|} = 1_G$ by taking $H = \langle x\rangle \subset G$.

I cannot understand how to use Lagrange's theorem here. I think, that if $H$ is sungroup of $G$, in $H$ should exist $1_G$, so some of the words, that constructed by $x$ is equivalent to $1_G$. If $n \times |\langle x\rangle | = |G|$ $\Rightarrow$ $|\langle x\rangle | = \frac{|G|}{n}$.  But how can I find that the $x^{|G|} = 1_G$?

Comment: If you don't write the whole question and just begin as you did, this doesn't look very serious...

Comment: This is literally a question from the textbook.

Comment: Either you're not reading properly that part of the book, or else you need to throw it away . What book begins a question with "Conclude"...there **must** be something before that which gently introduces you into what is being discussed!

Comment: You could phrase it better. Like: let $H= \langle x \rangle $ a subgroup of a finite group $G$, prove that $x^{|G|}=1$.

Comment: I agree with the above comments. The word "deduce" would be far better here. It sounds like you've just chopped off the last part of a longer question.

Comment: The question from this textbook http://web.evanchen.cc/napkin.html pg.57

Comment: @ArseniyO. ...and as already said: you deleted **all the first lines** of that section 3.4, which means: all the context! In particular, you ommited theorem 3.4.1.

Comment: what kind of content I have missed? that the G is finite group?

Comment: I've rewritten the question to make it clear (well, clearer). The comments above are really about the meaning of the word "conclude", so are about the English language rather than maths.

Comment: Arseniy O. That $G$ is a finite group is rather important: I really hope you understand this.

Comment: Yes, ofc, but I always think that the speaking about infinity groups in Lagrange's theorem -- weirdness

Comment: @user1729 I'm not sure that the comments everybody has made here are about the English language rather than maths. Use of the "correct" (that is to say, standard) terminology is crucial in communicating mathematics, whatever language it is delivered in. To be a good mathematician, you have to be a good communicator of mathematics. I understand that not everybody is born knowing the standard way of phrasing problems, but this is a good place for everybody to learn. As long as everybody's polite about it, I think pointing things like this out is beneficial.

Comment: @SamStreeter I agree that language and how we communicate is important, but the problem here really is that the OP was struggling to understand poor communication from the author of the book ("Conclude from the above that..." would have been better).

Comment: @user1729 I agree that the question was poorly written in the book. I wouldn't want to blame the OP for that.

Comment: @user1729 so in the textbook implied phrase "Conclude from the above that...", yes?

Comment: @Arsenii Yes. Conclude always has an "object" it is referring to. When you see the word "conclude" you should think "conclude *from what*?!?".

Comment: @user1729 okey, yes, now I am understand this english phrase, thx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $G$ is finite.

$\mid G\mid=n\cdot\mid H\mid$ by Lagrange.   Hence $x^{\mid G\mid}=x^{n\cdot \mid H\mid}=(x^{\mid H\mid})^n=1_G^n=1_G$.

Answer (score 2):

The order of $H$ is the same as the order of $x$ as an element of $G$. In particular, we have $x^{|H|} = 1_G$. Now use Lagrange's Theorem.

Answer (score 0):

Observe that $H$ is a cyclic gruop hence the order of $x$ is $n=|H|$ which implies that $x^n=1_G$ hence $x^{|G|}=1_G^{|G|/n}=1_G$

Comment: I think here shuld be: $n = |H|$ hence $x^n = 1_G$ and if $m\times |H| = |G|$ hence $m\times n = |G|$ hence $x^{m\times n} = 1_G \times x^m = x^m$. Why the $x^m = 1_G$?

Comment: $x^{m \cdot n}=(x^n)^m$, the equality $x^{m \cdot n}=x^m \cdot x^n$ is clearly false. The point is that $x^{m \cdot n}=(x^n)^m=(1_G)^m=1_G$.

Comment: @N.B. then I don’t really understand where we get this operation from on the exponents of the elements of the group.I'm sure you're right, but how is this operation going? The exponent is not an element of the group

Comment: I do not understand your comment: given an element in a group $x \in G$ and a natural number $n \in \mathbb{N}$ we can always define $x^n$ as the consecutive product of $n$ copies of $x$, i.e. $x^n= x \cdot x \cdot \dots \cdot x$ with $x^0=1_G$. Then we can extend this to $n$ an integer (thus also a negative number) by setting $x^{-k}=(x^{-1})^k$ where $k>0$ and $x^{-1}$ is the inverse of the element $x$ in the group $G$. This operation satisfies the usual properties of the exponential like $x^{m+n}=x^m \cdot x^n$ and $x^{m \cdot n}=(x^m)^n$.

Comment: @N.B. And how is it algebraically correct to call such a connection between structures? Between any groups and $\mathbb{N}$?

Comment: What do you mean "how it is algebraically correct"? I have defined this and you can verify easily this is well defined and has the properties I stated. Are you surprised that this gives a morphism of groups $\mathbb{Z} \rightarrow G$ for any group $G$? This is because $\mathbb{Z}$ is the free group generated by one element, thus the choice of one element $x \in G$ gives rise to a map $\mathbb{Z} \rightarrow G$ mapping the generator of $\mathbb{Z}$ to the chosen $x$.

Comment: But in your definition two operations are used. I.e, in your definition $\mathbb{Z}$ -- ring? And how we can associated that map between groups saving the rings operations with that?

Comment: The defined map is a morphism of groups: this means that the addition on $\mathbb{Z}$ translated on the group operation on $G$. Since $G$ is not a ring we cannot extend this to a morphism of rings (I think this is your observation). Even if $G$ were a ring this would not be a ring map in general (try to figure the case $G=(\mathbb{R}, +)$).  Nevertheless the equation $(x^n)^m=x^{n+m}$ holds by direct verification